# How to convert an Angular 2 project to work with IntelliJ Idea and its AngularJS plugin

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, typescript

After downloading (my company does not allow to clone) the "tour of heroes" git from :

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes

I open it in intellij IDEA and I would like to convert it to use it with the AngularJS plugin.

I tried to found a solution here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-angularjs.html

But :
- I can't create a new project because it uses an angular-seed from github (my company does not allows it)
- Its is explained to link an angular.js librairies but I use Angular 2 with TypeSpring and the node_modules/@angular are in typescript

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: my company provides IntelliJ Idea ( software are virtualized ) and not VSCode.